# Selecting interface to sniff in Python using a variable

Tags: python, sniffing

I need to create a sniff in python using the sniff command, to collect packets entering several interfaces.
When I do it specifying the interfaces with their names with the following command:

```
sniff(iface=["s1-cpu-eth1","s2-cpu-eth1","s3-cpu-eth1","s4-cpu-eth1"], prn=self.recv)
```

It works, but if I try to use a variable (this is needed because interfaces can change depending on the context and they can be obtained through a for loop populating a variable), such as:

```
if_to_sniff="\"s1-cpu-eth1\",\"s2-cpu-eth1\",\"s3-cpu-eth1\",\"s4-cpu-eth1\""

sniff(iface=[if_to_sniff], prn=self.recv)
```

It doesn't work.
I actually tried several ways, but I always get an error saying that the device doesn't exist. How can I do this?

Comment: Python doesn't understand you `[if_to_sniff]` the way you're trying to use it. Your question should be: how to i convert a string into a list. The answer to that is just `str.split()`.


`if_to_sniff="s1-cpu-eth1,s2-cpu-eth1,s3-cpu-eth1,s4-cpu-eth1".split(",")`


`sniff(iface=if_to_sniff, ...)`

Comment: You opened my eyes, I didn't understand that it was a list because I wasn't considering the function that [ and ] actually have inside the sniff command; I passed the interfaces as a list and know it works, thanks a lot for your support :-)

Answer (score 0):

```py
if_to_sniff="\"s1-cpu-eth1\",\"s2-cpu-eth1\",\"s3-cpu-eth1\",\"s4-cpu-eth1\""
```

This string looks like CSV format? In which case we can use Python's CSV reader to parse it for us:

```py
import csv

if_to_sniff="\"s1-cpu-eth1\",\"s2-cpu-eth1\",\"s3-cpu-eth1\",\"s4-cpu-eth1\""

# csv.reader expects a file or a list of strings (like lines in csv file)
reader = csv.reader([if_to_sniff])

# get the first row from our 'csv'
# interfaces will be the 'columns' of that row
# (i.e. split into a list of sub strings)
interfaces = reader.__next__()

sniff(iface=interfaces, prn=self.recv)
```